# How to load handlebars with requireJS

Tags: requirejs, handlebars.js

I am trying to load the handlebars with require js, but I am getting undefined.

```javascript
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'scripts',
    paths: {

        jquery: ['https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery',
            'jquery-3.5.1'],

        popper: ['https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2/dist/umd/popper.js'],

handlebars: ['handlebars-v4.7.6.js'],

       }
});
```

Comment: Do you have 404 in your browser?

Comment: I get net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND ..... Most probably I am not defining the handlebars function correctly.

Comment: define(['handlebars'], function (handlebars) {

    var carsObject = {
        "cars": [
        {
            "ShortLink": "nissan",
            "Brand": "Nissan",
            "Owner": "George",
            "Color": "Grey",
            "Price":"1500lv",
            "Fuel":"Diesel",
        },

Comment: This error means that file not found, so the server response is 404. Your paths are wrong, please double check them. Use network panel in the dev tools to see what url you are trying to load via requirejs